# React - deleting array elements stored in state deletes wrong element

Tags: reactjs

I've been beating my head against this for long enough that I'm not sure I'd even see an obvious problem.

The App has rows, and each row has cells of varying sizes.  Adding rows works.  Adding cells works.  Deleting rows however, does not.  If I click the delete button for row 0, row 2 disappears.  If I click the button for row 1, row 2 disappears.  Looking at the react dev tools, it appears that under the hood the right row is being deleted (in state), the right row is selected for deletion, but no matter what it doesn't render the way I would expect (if I hit delete for row 0, row 0 disappears, for example).

If I delete from the highest row down it works, but if I start at the zeroth row it won't let itself be deleted.

**deleteRowButtonHandler of the App class** is where I've been focusing my efforts.

```
deleteRowButtonHandler( e )
        {
            const targetRow = parseInt( e.target.id ) 
console.log( "TARGETING: ", targetRow )

            const currentRows = this.state.rows

            let newArray = []
            currentRows.forEach( entry =>
            {
                console.log( "Looking at ", entry.id )
                if( entry.id == targetRow )
                    console.log( 'skipping entry with id', entry.id )
                else
                    newArray.push( entry )
            })

            console.log( newArray )
            this.setState( {rows: newArray})
            //let newRows = currentRows.filter( thisRow => {console.log( thisRow.id + ' and the target ' +  targetRow);
             //   if( thisRow.id == targetRow )
             //   {
             //       console.log( thisRow )
             //       console.log( '...is the row that we are trying to delete' )
            //    }

            //    return thisRow.id !== targetRow} 
            //) 
            //this.setState( {rows: newArray}, console.log( "NEW STATE:", this.state ))
        }
```

I've tried a few variations (filter, splice, doing it in a few lines, doing it in a lot of lines, etc) so I'm not particularly proud of that chunk of code at the moment.

https://codepen.io/philipvdg/pen/mdmmWLG is the code; any pointers in the right direction would be greatly appreciated.

**Update**
Speaking generally, the problem was that I (being a newbie) didn't understand that the constructor was only run once.  In the constructor of a child component I had `this.cells = this.props.cells` and then, in the render method, called `this.cells.map( ... )`.  Since the constructor only ever ran once, `this.cells` was never updated after a state change.

Comment: Which version of the code are you asking about? The uncommented or commented one? Only include one version of code or show two different code snippets if you are showing two different attempts. Each code snippet should be such that we can copy/paste and run ourselves without any changes (such as uncommenting).

Comment: While you are debugging, be aware that the second parameter to `this.setState()` should be a callable. In the commented out version `console.log( "NEW STATE:", this.state )` is called immediately and its return value is passed to `this.setState()`. Instead, you probably want something like `newState => console.log( "NEW STATE:", newState)`.

Comment: @Code-Apprentice Yes, I'm aware of that, thank you.  In that particular case those two lines are vestigial remnants from various other attempts at getting this to work.  I've already learned the value of the setState callback.  Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It get duplicate ids somehow.

```
Looking at  3
    pen.js:74 Looking at  4
    pen.js:81 (4) [{…}, {…}, {…}, {…}]
    pen.js:225 TEMPLATE PROPS:  {rows: Array(4)}rows: Array(4)0: {cells: Array(0), id: 0}1: {cells: Array(1), id: 3}2: {cells: Array(0), id: 3}3: {cells: Array(0), id: 4}length: 4__proto__: Array(0)__proto__: Object
    pen.js:232 row 0 is {cells: Array(0), id: 0}
    pen.js:232 row 1 is {cells: Array(1), id: 3}
    pen.js:232 row 2 is {cells: Array(0), id: 3}
    pen.js:232 row 3 is {cells: Array(0), id: 4}

// in newRowButtonHandler
this.setState( { rows: [ ...this.state.rows, {cells:[], id: this.state.rows.length} ] } )

// try this
    this.setState( { rows: [ ...this.state.rows, {cells:[], id: Math.round(Math.random() * 1000000)} ] }) )
```

**UPD**
Problem with id's, render and delete function use different set of values. https://codepen.io/Asmyshlyaev177/pen/yLbXBGo?editors=0010

Should not use *e.target.id*, should be **single source of truth** e.g. react state.

Comment: That's certainly something I'll change once I get to the bottom of the current problem, thanks for pointing it out.  In the pre-loaded data (the rows that are hard-coded at the top of the code) there aren't duplicate IDs so I don't think that's directly related to the problem.

Comment: Working version, problem with how you use id's https://codepen.io/Asmyshlyaev177/pen/yLbXBGo?editors=0010

Comment: If you try to delete the zeroth row, it still doesn't get removed though.  With the default data, click the delete button on row zero and the row with the three col-xs-1 cells doesn't go anywhere.  I don't get what's wrong with using e.target.id - that just contains the id of the delete button which contains the row to delete.  Could you expand on why that's a bad idea?

Comment: You should have 1 place to store state, when you spread state between React and html attributes it much harder to track and easier to make mistakes, e.g. need to write some code to synchronize state in 2 places.

Comment: It didn't get removed because you assign cells from props to variable, but constructor function run only on first render.

Comment: I wasn't storing state in HTML, each row just had an ID that was contained in an HTML attribute.  For example, if you click the delete button on a row the delete button handler can pick up which row to delete by looking at the event source element's ID (line 161 in my code pen).  Maybe I'm not understanding your explanation correctly.

Comment: I understand your comment about assigning cells from props now, thank you.  For those of you playing along at home, in the constructor of Row I was assigning this.cells from props.cells and then iterating over that in the render method.  I wasn't aware that the constructor was only run once, so changing this.cells.map to this.props.cells.map corrected the problem.  Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

In `Controls` render you should add line `const id = row.id;` so it will be like this:

```
this.props.rows.map( 
   ( row ) => {
     const id = row.id; 
    let rowId = 'controlRow' + id
```

Using array idx is wrong. You should use idx from data structure.

Comment: "Wrong" as in it won't work or is it something that's just generally frowned upon for some reason?

Comment: Interesting, I've never heard of the array ID being buggy - is that a known/documented bug in Javascript or something specific to React?

Comment: You can read this article: https://robinpokorny.medium.com/index-as-a-key-is-an-anti-pattern-e0349aece318